# ajax results update from another function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a project which loads default results via an ajax call. The results are values which caches the data.

Now what I'm trying to do is to call another api call which will allow filtering these results based on a couple of user inputs(select option for example).

```
//default call on page
var res = {};
    function defaultResults() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/db/api.php",
        data: { db_func_name: results, fields: JSON.stringify({ user: id, customer_name: custname, location: location}) },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
          ....
        }
      });
    }
```

what i am trying to do for instance is the  following: I have a form that allows users to filter the results so, on change to get the response from defaultResults() but pass location val from select and clear prev results and update with the new ones.

```
$('#location').change(function(){
res = null; // also tried 
location = $(this).val();
 // call defaultResults() pass new location value
 // update results
});
```

or would i have to wrap the .change to a function and copy the defaultResults() call and pass new variable

```
function locChange(){
 $('#location').change(function(){
  function defaultResults() {
  $.ajax({
  url: "/db/api.php",
   data: { db_func_name: results, fields: JSON.stringify({ user: id, customer_name: custname, location: location}) },
          type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
        ....
       }
    });
 });
 }
```

or set the default location = home and detect on change ('#location') and fire defaultResults()

Comment: Will the `success` do same thing each time? Is the only difference the `location`?

Comment: It will return the results but only those with the selected location for example

Comment: That's understood. Trying to sort out what you need in your code is why I was asking. Your problem isn't entirely clear